# Laravel - Check name of named error bag

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

My registration form and login form are on the same page, but in different tabs. By default the active tab is login. While registering if there is any errors, the error messages are returned and I can print the error message at the right place by using named error bag.

The problem is when the error is from the registration form, the active tab should be register. For this I need to check the named of laravel validation.

How can I do that??

COde for validation is:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()
    ->withErrors($validator, 'register')
    ->withInput();
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-formrequest-class-named-errorbags?page=1
Looks like you can name the error bag: `protected $errorBag = 'login';`

Comment: No, I can differentiate the error message, but I need to get the name of error bag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using the `->hasBag()` method on the `$errors` variable to check if a bag exists for the given key, which would allow you to output the relevant CSS class or whatever you need to display the correct tab. For example:

```
<div class="tab registration{!! $errors->hasBag('register') ? ' active' : '' !!}">

</div>
```

`hasBag('register')` will return `true` if there's an error bag present for the registration form, assuming you've set up your validation to define which bag to use for registration errors. That will allow you to select the correct tab.

Comment: Did you change the key you're using to `register`? I put `registration` in my example above.

Comment: Yes, I changed to register.. (I'm using register)

Comment: Try using `dd($errors->getBags())` that should show you which bags are available at that moment. It should return an array, keyed by the identifier for each bag.

Comment: To access contents of the bag...
`@error('email', 'register')`
`<strong>{{ $message }}</strong>`
`@enderror`

Answer (score 0):

Your Tab link should be like below :

if /auth is route for your page then

for login tab :  `/auth#login` => this will display login tab

for register tab :  `/auth#register` => this will display register tab

```
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs tab-nav-right" role="tablist">
         <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#login" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#register" data-toggle="tab"></a</li>
  </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="login">
                <b>Login Form</b>


               @if (Request::path()=='auth#login' && count($errors) > 0)
                   @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                       <p class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">{{ $error }}
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        </p>
                   @endforeach
                @endif

          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="register">
                <b>Register Form</b>

                @if (Request::path()=='auth#register' && count($errors) > 0)
                   @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                       <p class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">{{ $error }}
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        </p>
                   @endforeach
                @endif
          </div>
```

in your controller for login tab error:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
        return  redirect('/auth#login')
                    ->withErrors($validator, 'login')
                    ->withInput();
    }
```

in your controller for register tab error:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
        return  redirect('/auth#register')
                    ->withErrors($validator, 'register')
                    ->withInput();
    }
```